# Spring nested transaction rollback after handling exception

Tags: java, spring, transactions, nested-transactions

I have a `@Service` class which has a `@Transactional` method that calls another `@Transactional` method on the another service. Something like that:

```
@Service
public class AService {
  @Autowired
  BService b;
  @Autowired
  ARepository aRepo;

  @Transactional
  public void methodOne(){
    try{
      b.methodTwo();
    }catch(RuntimeException e){}
    aRepo.save(new A());
  }

} 

@Service
public class BService{

    @Transactional
    public void methodTwo(){
      if(true)
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

}
```

I expect that A entity will be insert, but if any nested transaction throw exception insert will reject even this exception was handled at `AService.methodOne()`.

I can annotate `methodTwo()` with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`. But it will beat performance.

Comment: There is no nested transaction there is a single one. If you want separate transactions you ned to annotate the other one with `REQUIRES_NEW`. Yes that is a performance impact as it starts a new tx.

Comment: Have this case another more elegant solution ?

Comment: No. You either commit everything or rollback everything... You cannot partially commit stuff that would beat the ACID properties of a transaction.

Comment: If i move try-catch block into methodTwo() A entity insert successfully. But in my real methodOne i have a lot of method calls, and some of them is required for bussines logic.

Comment: did you find the solution? I'm also having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to rollback your transaction from `methodOne` after some exception happens in the `methodTwo`, you can add annotate `methodOne` with `@Transactional(noRollbackFor = {RuntimeException.class})`. But please be aware that this is a bit of slippery slope and think twice if you really want to do it.

Comment: methodOne()  has a lot of another service method calls, and this methods calls not only in AService. I want this behaviour only in AService.